# Markers not being drawn on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've written the below code and all is working grand from the point of view of data, the data is returned from the ajax call in JSON format like the snippet below.

The problem seems to be with the `addMarker` function, the data is passed into the function ok, I've verified this with an `alert()` from within the `addMarker` function but no markers are being plotted on the map and no errors are being thrown in the browser or console.

Do I need to call `setMapOnAll` after each marker is added to display it on the map? I've tried adding `setMapOnAll` to the end of the `addMarker` function but nothing changed.

JSON:

```
{id:278, title:"", lat:"52.50474200", lng:"-8.71032700"}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var map;
var markers = [];

function loadMap()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 12,
        zoom: 6,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    } else {
        map.setCenter({lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644});
    }

    loadMarkerData(-1);
}

function addMarker(lat, lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}


function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function loadMarkerData(selectedKeys, year, source)
{
    var data = {id: 1};

    if (selectedKeys != '' && year != '' && source != '') {
        data = {id: 1, selectedKeys:selectedKeys, year:year, source:source};
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "ajaxcall.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if (data != '') {
                markerObj = eval(data);

                $.each(markerObj, function(index, element) {
                    addMarker(element.lat, element.lng)
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original code, I get a javascript error: `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`, because those values are strings.  You can fix that by changing this:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng 
        },
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

To:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: parseFloat(lat),
            lng: parseFloat(lng)
        },
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: Which is the correct way to do this, using `parsefloat` or `new google.maps.LatLng()`, is there more of an overhead with `new google.maps.LatLng()`?

Comment: Either works, your "explaination" for why you needed to use a `google.maps.LatLng` didn't make sense to me (I didn't see where you were "building a string"), I have to assume that method coerces the string arguments you are passing in into numbers internally.